# High Poly modeling pinching in corner

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm working on a high poly Lancia Fulvia but struggling with some pinching in certain places of the model and I'm not sure how I'm able to get rid of this.
I'm guessing there's a better way for me to support the corner but I'm not sure how.
Any ideas?

Edit: Added part of the mesh + one of the better real life references I have of this part of the car.

Link to the blend file of the mesh:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R--psoI6_bRXm2XUXirzrJIQ-EjBV3dI

[image: Pinching in the corner]
[image: Geometry]
[image: Real reference]

Comment: maybe share this part of your mesh and also a picture of this part of the real object

Comment: @moonboots edited the original post, added one of my better references of the top of the hood and added a blend file with the part of the mesh where the pinching is occuring

Comment: I need an authorization to download, could you use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that since the inner corner is very slightly lower (in my mesh) than the edges on the outside pinching is inevitable in this corner.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this part seems rather flat if we judge from your picture, so I guess it would give something like this:

[image]